# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...} after installing Android SDK Build-Tools 26

Tags: java, android, sdk, build-tools, android-version

I upgraded Android Studio to 2.3.3

and then I installed Android SDK Build-Tools 26

and Android 8.0 (O)

and set compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion on 26

and buildToolsVersion on "26.0.0"

and then I changed all the libraries version from 25.3.1 to 26.0.0-alpha1

Now I have the below RunTime Exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mysite.myapp/com.mysite.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2480)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1377)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5725)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1030)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:825)
>                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
>                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
>                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>                                                                             at com.mysite.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
>                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6018)
>                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2480) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1377) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5725) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1030) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Setting FragmentDrawer{28990c1 #0 id=0x7f0f0095} as the target of FragmentDrawer{28990c1 #0 id=0x7f0f0095} would create a target cycle
>                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setTargetFragment(Fragment.java:636)
>                                                                             at com.mysite.myapp.Fragments.FragmentDrawer.onCreate(FragmentDrawer.java:83)
>                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2226)
>                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
>                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1502)
>                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1737)
>                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3512)
>                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
>                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:330)
>                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
>                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
>                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
>                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289) 
>                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>                                                                             at com.mysite.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65) 
>                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6018) 
>                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2480) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1377) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5725) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1030) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:825)

the (MainActivity.java:65) and (FragmentDrawer.java:83) are displayed as link.

MainActivity.java:65 content:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

FragmentDrawer.java:83 content:

```
setTargetFragment(FragmentDrawer.this, 100);
```

before MainActivity there is a SplashActivity and it runs without any problem!

I've just downgraded SDK Build-Tools, compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion and libraries version to run again and test. there is no problem using previews versions.

Can anyone help me? How can I run my App using new SDK Version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Setting FragmentDrawer{28990c1 #0 id=0x7f0f0095} as the target of
FragmentDrawer{28990c1 #0 id=0x7f0f0095} would create a target cycle
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setTargetFragment(Fragment.java:636)
```

`setTargetFragment` has changed in `26.0.0`. Before, it simply set the target fragment plus request code. From `26.0.0` onwards, it contains two checks before doing that:
- it checks whether the current fragment and the target fragment belong to the same fragment manager
- it checks whether setting the target fragment would create a loop, by scanning the list of target fragments in this fragment and see if the target fragment is already there.

So somehow you are setting a target fragment that you set before. That is no longer allowed.

Comment: I commented `setTargetFragment(FragmentDrawer.this, 100);` and the crash didn't occur anymore. thank you.